# Not able to run Android App on Emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am learning `android` app development as a beginner. The app is not running on the emulator. The Error says:

> Unfortunately,Appname has stopped.

I have gone through the similar topics solved here, but I am still unable to find the problem. From the `logcat` logs it appears that there is a timeout issue but on increasing the timeout value to 50 sec through eclipse -> window -> preferences -> Android -> DDMS, its still showing the same **error**.
Any help?

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener{

private Button theButton;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    theButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    theButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v){
    if(v.getId()==theButton.getId()){
         theButton.setText("Ouch");
     }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat**

```
01-02 11:39:23.260: W/WearableConn(485): Error writing to device, error: failed to     connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 5601): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
01-02 11:39:23.310: I/WearableConn(485): Socket closed
01-02 11:39:23.360: I/WearableConn(485): Waiting 2.0 seconds to retry connection
01-02 11:39:25.400: I/WearableConn(485): Connecting via TCP to /10.0.2.2:5601
01-02 11:39:25.480: D/dalvikvm(455): GC_EXPLICIT freed 888K, 30% free 3283K/4632K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 48ms
01-02 11:39:33.190: I/Choreographer(455): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 11:39:33.220: I/ActivityManager(354): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.myfirstapp/.MainActivity} from pid 455 on display 0
01-02 11:39:33.260: D/LightsService(354): Excessive delay setting light: 63ms
01-02 11:39:33.410: D/gralloc(49): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
01-02 11:39:33.410: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
01-02 11:39:33.420: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
01-02 11:39:33.420: W/WindowManager(354): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (123x221) to layer 21000
01-02 11:39:33.420: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
01-02 11:39:33.420: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
01-02 11:39:33.420: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error -1331883460
01-02 11:39:33.420: E/SurfaceFlinger(49): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
01-02 11:39:33.420: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
01-02 11:39:33.420: E/libEGL(49): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
01-02 11:39:33.460: I/Choreographer(354): Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 11:39:33.590: D/LightsService(354): Excessive delay setting light: 61ms
01-02 11:39:33.620: I/ActivityManager(354): Start proc com.example.myfirstapp for activity com.example.myfirstapp/.MainActivity: pid=745 uid=10018 gids={50018}
01-02 11:39:33.640: D/dalvikvm(745): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455): Failed to send RPC
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455): com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.WearableException: sendRpcAsync failed: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 4000, resolution=null}
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.GoogleApiClientHelper.throwIfFailed(GoogleApiClientHelper.java:98)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1$1.getResult(MessageManager.java:81)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1$1.getResult(MessageManager.java:78)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.clockwork.actions.WearableHostWithRpcCallback$SendRpcCallbackWithId.onSendRpc(WearableHostWithRpcCallback.java:292)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1.onResult(MessageManager.java:78)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1.onResult(MessageManager.java:75)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$CallbackHandler.deliverResultCallback(Unknown Source)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
01-02 11:39:33.670: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 11:39:34.030: D/AndroidRuntime(745): Shutting down VM
01-02 11:39:34.030: W/dalvikvm(745): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4a22d70)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID: 745
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2197)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1209)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:277)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2889)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3154)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superSetContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:217)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:110)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:77)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5242)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
01-02 11:39:34.040: E/AndroidRuntime(745):  ... 11 more
01-02 11:39:34.100: W/ActivityManager(354):   Force finishing activity com.example.myfirstapp/.MainActivity
01-02 11:39:34.120: W/InputMethodManagerService(354): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b4ebb730 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b4e0fa08
01-02 11:39:34.350: I/Choreographer(354): Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 11:39:34.470: I/Choreographer(354): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 11:39:34.570: I/Choreographer(354): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 11:39:34.620: I/Choreographer(354): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 11:39:34.630: W/ActivityManager(354): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b4eb1738 u0 com.example.myfirstapp/.MainActivity t4 f}
01-02 11:39:34.690: I/Choreographer(354): Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 11:39:34.730: I/Choreographer(354): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455): Failed to send RPC
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455): com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.WearableException: sendRpcAsync failed: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 4000, resolution=null}
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.GoogleApiClientHelper.throwIfFailed(GoogleApiClientHelper.java:98)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1$1.getResult(MessageManager.java:81)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1$1.getResult(MessageManager.java:78)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.clockwork.actions.WearableHostWithRpcCallback$SendRpcCallbackWithId.onSendRpc(WearableHostWithRpcCallback.java:292)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1.onResult(MessageManager.java:78)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.MessageManager$1.onResult(MessageManager.java:75)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$CallbackHandler.deliverResultCallback(Unknown Source)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.BaseImplementation$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5026)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
01-02 11:39:34.830: E/HostWithRpcCallback(455):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 11:39:35.640: I/Process(745): Sending signal. PID: 745 SIG: 9
01-02 11:39:35.660: I/ActivityManager(354): Process com.example.myfirstapp (pid 745) has died.
01-02 11:39:35.750: W/InputMethodManagerService(354): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b4f00610 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b4e0fa08
01-02 11:39:35.800: I/Choreographer(354): Skipped 166 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-02 11:39:35.880: D/dalvikvm(354): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 502K, 13% free 4406K/5048K, paused 63ms, total 69ms
01-02 11:39:35.890: I/Choreographer(354): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: 4.4W is Android Wear SDK change your SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Error logs clearly says the error caused by:

```
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine swipe dismissal and the action bar.
```

4.4W is Android Wear SDK. Just Don't the Android wear SDK and change the  target sdk version to 19 in your Androidmanifest.xml file as shown here

Inside manifest tag add this tag if doesn't exist already

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Don't use API Level 20 as Android Virtual Device. Use API level 19 and platform 4.4.2 instead.

Comment: I am changing the SDK version...

Comment: Does it solved your problem ?

Comment: yes it is working with SdkVersion 19

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and solved by:
`Open the android SDK manager and remove Android wear sdk and its package completely and try to run you android application.`